# Renault Laguna 2004

Tags: electrical, renault, laguna

I am charging my car battery indoors. So my car is unlocked at moment.

Can I lock it using the pull out key on card key without battery connected. ??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use the mechanical key to lock it with no battery installed, should be instructions in the manual